# Porblema con un if y un else

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy intentando resolver este problema:

Escribe un programa que lea dos secuencias de  enteros cada una y determine si cada elemento de la primera secuencia es mayor que el elemento respectivo de la segunda secuencia.

Y esto es lo que tengo:

```
int main()
{   
   int a;

   cin>>a;

   int arr[a];
   int brr[a];

   for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
      cin>>arr[a];
   }

   for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
      cin>>brr[a];
   }

   int x = 0;

   for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
      if(arr[i] > brr[i])
      {
         x = 1;
         break;
      }
      else
      {
         x = 0;
      }
   }

   cout<<x; 
}
```

El problema es que solo me imprime lo que contiene el if y el else no lo toma en cuenta, me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal.

Esto es lo que se supone tiene que salir como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Así como leo tu código, entiendo que está diciendo _ni bien encuentres que el primer valor de la primera secuencia es mayor al primer valor de la segunda secuencia, cortá el bucle e imprimí que x es 1_. Error de lógica, no estás comparando _todos los valores_ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool esMayorPrimerArreglo = true;
bool esMayorSegundoArreglo = true;    

for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
   if(arr[i] <= brr[i])
   {
      esMayorPrimerArreglo = false;
   }
   else if(brr[i] <= arr[i])
   {
      esMayorSegundoArreglo = false;
   }       
}

if(esMayorPrimerArreglo)
{
   cout<<"1";
}
else if(esMayorSegundoArreglo)
{
   cout<<"0";
}

system("pause");
```

Después de llenar los arreglos como ya tu haces declaras las **variables booleanas esMayorPrimerArreglo** y **esMayorSegundoArreglo** , que por defecto se inicializan con el valor **true**. Posteriormente harías un **ciclo for** para recorrer ambos arreglos, si se cumple la condición:

```
(arr[i] <= brr[i])
```

entonces ya los elementos del primer arreglo no son mayores a los elementos del segundo arreglo, por lo que la **variable esMayorPrimerArrglo** toma el valor de **false**.

De igual modo si se cumple la condición:

```
(brr[i] <= arr[i])
```

entonces los elementos del segundo arreglo no son mayores a los elementos del primer arreglo, por lo que la **variable esMayorSegundoArreglo** toma el valor de **false**.

Después de salir del **ciclo for** se pregunta si la **variable esMayorPrimerArreglo** es **true**, en caso de cumplirse esta condición imprimes el resultado deseado, en caso de no cumplirse se pregunta entonces si la **variable esMayorSegundoArreglo** es **true** y se imprime el resultado deseado.

Comment: Lo hice como esta la parte del if y else, pero solo me imprime el 0, osea que solo esta entrando en el else y el if no lo toma en cuenta.

Comment: Hazlo como te dije, de esta forma te ahorras el else en el ciclo @ed_sgs

Comment: Asi es como lo hice (Mirar la otra solucion) y solo pasa al else. Osea que solo me marca el 0 y en el if no entra.

Comment: @ed_sgs no entiendo cual es tu complicacion, lo que yo te dije funciona, hazlo asi y pruebalo

Comment: @ed_sgs pasa el else pq no todos los elementos de la primera secuencia son mayores a los de la segunda

Comment: el cuarto elemento de tu primera y segunda secuencia es un 7, y como 7 no es mayor que 7, entonces se cumple el else, entiendes?

Comment: El problema es que yo no quiero imprimir todos los elementos que son mayores al otro arreglo, lo que yo quiero imprimir es "1" si el primer arreglo es mayor que el segundo o imprimir un "0" si el segundo arreglo es mayor que el primero. Eso es lo que yo quiero hacer

Comment: @ed_sgs es que eso no es lo que habias dado a entender en tu pregunta, solamente hablabas de que el primer arreglo fuera mayor al segundo, asi q escribe bien

Comment: Por eso es que puse en la parte de abajo del codigo, como es que tenia que salir la respusta, que tu no la hayas visto ya es otra cosa.

Comment: @ed_sgs revisa lo nuevo q puse

Comment: Perdon pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema.  Y pongo exactamnete como lo tienes. Solo que esta vez al momento de que imprima lo que deseo, no imprime nada.

Comment: @ed_sgs pero el mensaje de impresion lo tienes q poner tu, yo simplemente me limite a explicarte el algoritmo, el "0" o el "1" lo pones tu donde te escribi los comentarios dentro de las barras //

Comment: Si lo pongo dentro del if coloco cout<<"1" y dentro del else if coloco cout<<"0". Pero no me imprime ninguno de los dos, solo da por terminado el programa.

Comment: @ed_sgs lo que quieres decir es que el programa se cierra inmediatamente despues q lo ejecutas, es decir se cierra solo?

Comment: Se queda abierta la ventana de la consola, pero no imprime nada. Al momento de dar enter despues de escribir el segundo arreglo y ver que imprime si es uno o cero, no imprime nada y da por terminado el programa.

Comment: @ed_sgs para evitar q la consola se cierre debes poner system("pause"), yo pense q eso tu lo sabias por eso nunca hice referencia a ello, al poner esta instruccion la consola se cerrara al apretar una tecla

Comment: @ed_sgs podrias decirme si se resolvio tu problema, gracias?

Comment: Lo siento, ni poniendo el system("pause") se soluciono.

Comment: @ed_sgs realmente no se cual es tu problema pq el codigo q te di funciona, asi q revisa bien todo y se mas descriptivo para q se te pueda entender